# Making an RPN program that involves converting postfix to infix. Stuck on trying to build a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, tree, rpn

So basically the way I'm trying to go about solving this part of the problem is by using a bst. I believe a bst is the best way to go about this because once its in the tree you can start from the bottom and go from left, top, and right and an infix expression is made. For example, if you take the rpn expression "5 4 +" and start from the end, the "+" is the root of the tree, and the left and right nodes are 5 and 4. Then, going from left, to the top and to the right you get 5 + 4. The specifications are that I have to correctly parenthesize everything too for larger expressions; "5 4 + 3 * 2 /" would have to become "((5 + 5) * 3) / 2".

My infix function just prints out the tree in linear form for now. Obviously something is wrong with they way I'm trying to build the tree because "1 5 A" is printed out as "A 5 5".. actually no matter what I type it only prints out three things which is telling me its only storing a max of three things.. Anyways, programs in bad shape I feel, and I suck at C, and any help would be greatly appreciated. There's probably some obvious mistakes but my brains too fried to notice any of them. My other college classes make it hard to focus on programming.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX 100;

#define OP_EVAL "-e"
#define OP_INFX "-c"
#define OP_GENI "-g"

struct btree {
  int data;
  int isop;
  struct btree *left; 
  struct btree *right;
};

typedef struct btree node;

int is_oper(char ch);

node*
insert(char** argv, int index){
  node *tree;
  if(index < 1)
    return NULL;
  if(is_oper(argv[index][0])){
    tree = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tree->data = (int)argv[index][0];
    index--;
    tree->right = insert(argv, index);
    tree->left = insert(argv, index);
    tree->isop = 1;
    return tree;
  }
  else{
    tree = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->data = atoi(&argv[index][0]);
    tree->isop = 0;
    index--;
    return tree;
  }  
}

enum method
{
  EVAL,
  INFX,
  GENI
};

int 
is_option(const char *str)
{
  return (strcmp(str, OP_EVAL) == 0) ||
         (strcmp(str, OP_INFX) == 0) ||
         (strcmp(str, OP_GENI) == 0);
}

enum method
manip_method(const char *arg)
{
  if (strcmp(arg, OP_EVAL) == 0)
    return EVAL;
  else if (strcmp(arg, OP_INFX) == 0)
    return INFX;
  else if (strcmp(arg, OP_GENI) == 0)
    return GENI;
  else
    return 0;
}

int
is_oper(char ch){
  if(ch == 'A' || ch == 'S' || ch == 'X' || ch == 'D' || ch == 'M')
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

void 
infix(node *root){

  if(root != NULL){
    if(root->isop){
      printf("%c ",(char)root->data);
    }
    else{
      printf("%d ", root->data);
    }
    infix(root->left);
    infix(root->right);
  }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  node *root;
  root = NULL;
  enum method method;
  int x;
  if (argc >= 4){
    if (is_option(argv[1])){
      if (argc < 5){
    printf("not a valid calculatable expression, exiting now...\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      x = 2;
      method = manip_method(argv[1]);
    }
    else {
      x = 1;
      method = EVAL;
    }
  } else {
    printf("need option and or a valid reverse polish notation expression, exiting now...\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  root = insert(argv, argc-x);

  infix(root);

  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: So many SO questions lately regarding this exercice...

Comment: that would probably be my small computer science class lol